# Conversion of String into double get error

Tags: string, double, converters

I am capturing ouput value of external .exe file in java through this code

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("filepath\\myexefile.exe 5.53 46.46"); // 5.53 and 46.46 are two input orguments of exe file
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

String s;
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);                         }
    Double d = Double.valueOf(s);
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Code run fine and it shows the output 53.4429 as expected.However when I try to convert 53.4429 into double it gives the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1008)
    at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:504)
```

Any idea why string is not coverting into double? thanks in advance

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic that's really not helpful here. The OP has shown us the failing code, and the resultant stack trace.

Comment: I mean what he tried to figure out the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Because the loop runs until `s` is null, and *then* you're passing `s` – which is now `null`, remember – to `Double#valueOf(String)`.

To fix this, **parse `s` inside the loop.**

```
String s;
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
    Double d = Double.valueOf(s);
    System.out.println(d);
}
```